# verify integrity of encrypted tar

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, tar

I'm using tar along with openssl to create encrypted tar archives of some large directories (about 30GB).  What is the possibility of corruption in this process, and how would I verify that the encrypted tar archives are not corrupted?

This is the command I'm using to make the encrypted archives:

`tar cvzf - /secret_dir | openssl enc -aes256 -salt -pass file:passfile > encrypted_data.tar.gz`

Answer (score 3):

**What is the possibility of corruption in this process?**
Minimal. Note the standard caveats of `tar` though (may not deal well with files that are open and changing).

**how would I verify that the encrypted tar archives are not corrupted?**
Easiest way? Decrypt them and pipe them through `tar -tf -`.  If `tar` is satisfied, the archive is OK (again, subject to the standard caveats of `tar`, i.e. "I can restore what was stored in the archive, no problem! Now whether that's what you WANT, that's another story…").

---

If this is something you may be doing regularly you probably want to look into more comprehensive backup software ([Bacula](http://bacula.org) can do encryption - things are crypted on their way off the client - and has a pretty robust feature set).
If it's just a one-shot deal what you're proposing is fine (just don't lose that key!)